# Spring RabbitMq Listener Configuration

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are using RabbitMq with default spring boot configurations. We have a use case in which we want  no parallelism for one of the listeners. That is, we want only one thread of the consumer to be running at any given point in time. We want this, because the nature of the use case is such that we want the messages to be consumed in order, thus if there are multiple threads per consumer there can be chances that the messages are processed out of order.
Since, we are using the defaults and have not explicitly tweaked the container, we are using the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. By looking at the documentation I tried fixing the number of consumers using `concurrency = "1"` . The annotation on the target method looks like this `@RabbitListener(queues = ["queue-name"], concurrency = "1")`.

As per the documentation this should have ensured that there is only consumer thread.

> {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer
> * SimpleMessageListenerContainer} if this value is a simple integer, it sets a fixed
> * number of consumers in the {@code concurrentConsumers} property

```
2021-10-29 06:11:26.361 INFO  29752 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.xxx         : Created xxx
2021-10-29 06:11:26.383 INFO  29752 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.xxx         : Created xxx
```

ThreadIds to be noted here are `[ntContainer#4-1]` and `[ntContainer#0-1]`.

So the question is- how can we ensure that there is only one thread per consumer at any given point in time ?

Edit: Adding the code of the consumer class for more context

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = ["rabbitmq.sharebooking.enabled"], havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
class ShareBookingConsumer @Autowired constructor(
    private val shareBookingRepository: ShareBookingRepository,
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    private val shareDtoToShareBookingConverter: ShareBookingDtoToShareBookingConverter
) {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    init {
        logger.info("start sharebooking created consumer")
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = ["tax_engine.share_booking"], concurrency = "1-1", exclusive = true)
    @Timed
    @Transactional
    fun consumeShareBookingCreatedEvent(message: Message) {
        try {
            consumeShareBookingCreatedEvent(message.body)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e)
        }
    }

    private fun consumeShareBookingCreatedEvent(event: ByteArray) {
        toShareBookingCreationMessageEvent(event).let { creationEvent ->
            RmqMetrics.measureEventMetrics(creationEvent)
            val shareBooking = shareDtoToShareBookingConverter.convert(creationEvent.data)
            val persisted = shareBookingRepository.save(shareBooking)
            logger.info("Created shareBooking ${creationEvent.data.id}")
        }
    }

    private fun toShareBookingCreationMessageEvent(event: ByteArray) =
        objectMapper.readValue(event, shareBookingCreateEventType)

    companion object {
        private val shareBookingCreateEventType =
            object : TypeReference<RMQMessageEnvelope<ShareBookingCreationDto>>() {}
    }
}

Edit: Adding application thread analysis using visualvm
5 threads get created for 5 listeners.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQINE.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `concurrency = "1-1"`. Note that the concurrency of the Listener depends not only on `concurrentConsumers`, but also on `maxConcurrentConsumers`:

[image]

If you are using a custom factory:

```
  @Bean
  public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
    return factory;
  }
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#simplemessagelistenercontainer for detail.

EDIT:
I did a simple test, 2 consumers&2 threads:

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue111", concurrency = "1-1")
  public void handleMessage(Object message) throws InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.info("Received message : {} in {}", message, Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue222", concurrency = "1-1")
  public void handleMessag1e(Object message) throws InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.info("Received message222 : {} in {}", message, Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }
```

[image]

Comment: this is the annotation that I am using right now - 
`@RabbitListener(queues = ["queue-name"], concurrency = "1-1", exclusive = true)`
but I still see 2 threads in the application logs. 
I see the log for starting the consumer exactly once, which is great.
`2021-11-09 20:32:02.990 DEBUG 4418 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@61ecf3d6: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0`
but I still see [ntContainer#0-1] and [ntContainer#4-1] in the logs for the same consumer.

Comment: You have five ```RabbitListener``` with different queue, meaning there will be five threads: ```ntContainer#0-1, ntContainer#1-1, ntContainer#2-1`,ntContainer#3-1, ntContainer#4-1`` one for each listener.   But the consumer of each queue should always be the same thread.

Comment: the problem is it's the same consumer processing on different threads. 
[ntContainer#0-1]  and [ntContainer#4-1] are getting created for the same consumer. This I can confirm by looking at the logs
```2021-11-09 20:32:03.345 INFO  4418 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 904ad244-c57b-4e53-bb12-62a63271277d and 021-11-09 20:32:03.369 INFO  4418 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 43fc735b-c2d7-4531-9f70-77e24ddab6b8```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code for the ```ShareBookingConsumer```class? @aashish

Comment: added the code snippet for consumer @zysaaa

Comment: As far as I know, I really don't think it will happen. Can you test it locally? Then use some tools to view the application threads. @aashish

Comment: i used visual vm for thread analysis on my local machine and 5 threads get created as expected for each of the listeners and I generated artificial traffic for the consumer using the raabitmq console and each message gets consumed by the same thread.
```2021-11-10 14:59:40.014 INFO  59277 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 804ad244-c57b-4e53-bb12-62a63271277e 
2021-11-10 14:59:50.553 INFO  59277 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 704ad244-c57b-4e53-bb12-62a63271277e .
```

Comment: added screenshot in original question

Comment: This is supposed to happen.  So is there a problem with other environments?  @aashish

Comment: this happens when an integration test case runs on buildkite(we use it for CI/CD ). But I don't see any special configuration that we have done for the test environment. As we are using docker, the same rabbit server boots up locally as on the test environment. And there is no different configuration for the listeners as well for the test environment.

Comment: and just for more context, the application context and the server is started all over again so there is no chance of one test case interfering with the other.

Comment: Will there be only one Instance of  ```ShareBookingConsumer```?  Try add ```LOGGER.info(String.valueOf(this.hashCode()));```  check if it is the same instance?@aashish

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This is the problem, indeed multiple instances are getting created when I logged the hashcode.
```Created shareBooking 394027127 904ad244-c57b-4e53-bb12-62a63271277d 
 Created shareBooking 966991173 43fc735b-c2d7-4531-9f70-77e24ddab6b8
 Created shareBooking 394027127 4b50df3a-dc63-42b6-b2dc-e4962217de90
 Created shareBooking 324790669 5ff18a7b-aff0-4927-8c53-661cf3cc24a5```

394027127 & 966991173  being an example of different hashcodes. Now I can move on to the next piece of the puzzle as to why spring is not ensuring singletons.

Comment: It would be nice to accept the answer or vote. :) @aashish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["queue-name"], exclusive = true)
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#exclusive-consumer

Comment: `2021-11-09 18:56:01.898 INFO  884 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.    Created
 2021-11-09 18:56:01.931 INFO  884 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.        : Created`

Tried your suggestion but got the same result as per the application logs.
This is the annotation I used

`@RabbitListener(queues = ["queue-name"], concurrency = "1", exclusive = true)`

Comment: How many RabbitListener annotations does your spring app have ?

Comment: we have 5 `@RabbitListener` annotations in the application but each is bound to a different queue. I tried to debug more after enabling spring amqp debug logging.
this log
`2021-11-09 20:32:02.990 DEBUG 4418 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@61ecf3d6: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0`
only comes once which kind of ensures that `concurrency` settings are being correctly honoured. If i set `concurrency = "10"` , I see 10 such logs.

Comment: I see. So why do you think there is parallelism in your Listener. If you see only [ntContainer#0-1] it means that you have only one consumer for that listener. [ntContainer#4-1] is another consumer for another listener.

Comment: that cannot be the case that the log is coming from a different listener. 
If I present the full logs to you
`2021-11-09 20:32:03.345 INFO  4418 --- [ntContainer#4-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 904ad244-c57b-4e53-bb12-62a63271277d`

and 
`021-11-09 20:32:03.369 INFO  4418 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.t.t.i.p.s.ShareBookingConsumer         : Created shareBooking 43fc735b-c2d7-4531-9f70-77e24ddab6b8`
So it's the same class and method being triggered. There is only one `@RabbitListener` annotation in the class `ShareBookingConsumer`

Comment: Ok, sorry, i can't help you without code inspection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239079/discussion-between-aashish-and-martin-mondino).

Comment: just as a comment `exclusive = true` doesn't work without `concurrency = "1"` . May be you can edit your answer.